# updated_at timestamp not being updated when using sync in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I use the following code to update tags and other information about an organization:

```
Route::put('org/{org}', function(Org $org){
    $org->description = Input::get('description');
    $org->website = Input::get('website');
    $org->save();

    $org->tags()->sync(Input::get('tags'));

    return Redirect::to('org/'.$org->id)
        ->with('message', 'Seccessfully updated page!');
});
```

However, if I only change the tags associated with this org, the updated_at field is not updated. I added `protected $touches = array('org');` to my Tag model, but this only seems to work for belongsTo relations, while the relation between orgs and tags is a many-to-many polymorphic relation.

Is there a way to allow the sync function to automatically update the default updated_at timestamp?

Doing it manually, like below, will update the timestamp even if my edit doesn't actually change anything:

```
$org->updated_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
$org->save();
```

Comment: Which timestamp exactly?

Comment: Edited question. I'm talking about the default updated_at timestamp that should be automatically maintained when saving a model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to setup `touches` array on `Tag` model, BUT it has limitation:

Eloquent guesses the relation name, so will work only if the name complies with the convention.

`Organization` model -> `organizations` relation.

And if you want to manually update the timestamp you can use this instead:

```
$model->touch();
```

Comment: My org model/table aren't set up according to the convention, so that's probably why setting up the touches array didn't work. I ended up doing it manually - I will just mark your answer as accepted.